# Populating dictionary from RecordSet

Tags: sql, vba, excel, dictionary, recordset

I'm wondering if anyone can help me. I'm trying to populate a public dictionary from a recordset returned from an sql table.

It all seems to work fine, except one part. I don't know if it's not counting the number of keys in the dictionary correctly, or they aren't being entered correctly but for whatever reason when I try and show the total count, it always comes back with only 1 (supposed to be around 15) and only displays the first row details.

Can anyone help?

```
Public UserList As New scripting.Dictionary
Sub UserDL()
Dim USList As Range
Dim USArr(0 To 11) As Variant

Call ConnecttoDB

Set Cmd = New adodb.Command: Set rs = New adodb.Recordset

With Cmd
    .CommandTimeout = 30
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = "CSLL.DLUsers"

    Set rs = .Execute
End With

With rs
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        While (Not .EOF)
            For i = 1 To 11
                USArr(i - 1) = rs(i)
            Next i

                With UserList
                    If Not .Exists(rs("Alias")) Then
                        .Add Key:=rs("Alias"), Item:=USArr
                    End If
                End With
            .MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
End With

IA = UserList.Items
Debug.Print UserList.Count & " Items in the dictionary"
For Each element In IA
    For i = 0 To 10
        Debug.Print element(i)
    Next i
Next element

Set Cmd = Nothing: Set rs = Nothing ': Set UserList = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store `rs("Alias")` in a variable and then use that variable as key.

```
 dim sKey as String

    With UserList
    sKey=rs("Alias")
       If Not .Exists(sKey) Then
           .Add sKey,USArr
       End If
     End With
```

Comment: How annoying - worked perfectly first try. Thanks a lot for this! I've spent hours on it. Any reason behind declaring it as a variable first out of curiosity?

Comment: Without a data type, dictionary stores a pointer to the memory location instead of memory itself. So all iterations pointed to same location.

Answer (score 5):

rs("Alias") is a Field object. The default property for a Field object is Value, so normally just referring to the Field object gives us what we want - the value. However, a Dictionary can store objects (as the value or the key), so when you add an object it actually stores the object rather than the default property. So in your code, you add rs("Alias") as a key, i.e. the object and not the value. When you move to the next record, rs("Alias") is still the same object - only the value has changed. Therefore when you check if the key exists, it does. You need to add the Value property as the key.

The reason aa_dd's answer works is because it stores the value in a variable and then uses that value as the key, i.e. not the Field object.

An alternative approach is to explicitly use the Value property of the Field object...

```
With UserList
    If Not .Exists(rs("Alias").Value) Then
        .Add Key:=rs("Alias").Value, Item:=USArr
    End If
End With
```